# Postgres PIVOT SQL

Tags: postgresql, pivot

[image]

This table will store the each items value in percent on date wise and I need the results like below. Any help is much appreciated.TIA

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPh0j.png)

Comment: [Crosstab questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+and+%28%5Bpivot%5D+or+%5Bcrosstab%5D%29)

Comment: Please use plain text in your topic, that's something others can work with.
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.